# How to decrypt an xml file saved with a Transformer with an encrypted stream?

Tags: java, xml, encryption

I have to use the following code (I inherited it from a previous worker) for creating xml files:

```
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(CryptoHandler.encryptedStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)));
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

where encryptedStream returns a CipherOutputStream. I thought that I could use the following code to decrypt this file:

```
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(CryptoHandler.decryptedStream(new FileInputStream(fileName)));
xmlReader.setContentHandler(contentHandler.newInstance());
xmlReader.parse(inputSource);
```

where decryptedStream() uses the previously used key, but I get a **SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog** at the very first charachter.

**UPDATE #1:**

The code that verifies encryption and decryption:

```
CipherOutputStream cos = null;
CipherInputStream cis = null;
String text = "Some text to encryptSome text to encrypt";
String filePath = "D:/test.txt";
String result = "";        

cos = CryptoHandler.encryptedStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
cos.write(text.getBytes());
cos.flush();
cos.close();

cis = CryptoHandler.decryptedStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
byte[] buffer = new byte[text.getBytes().length];
while (cis.read(buffer) != -1) {
    result += new String(buffer);
}

Assert.assertEquals(text, result);
```

**UPDATE #2:**

I have found that the above test is OK, but for this specific string only, if I change its length to a different value, there will be some missing bytes at the end after decryption (it varies from 4 to basicly most of the data inserted). Although at some special length it works (2,4,8,16,24,40,80). This encryption method uses a **PBEWithMD5AndDES** cipher.

Comment: Check that `CryptoHandler.decryptedStream(CryptoHandler.encryptedStream(someStream)) == someStream`. "Content is not allowed in prolog" means the input of the xml reader contains some garbage at the very beginning, and the first suspect is that decoding and encoding is not properly paired.

Comment: 'CryptoHandler.decryptedStream()' needs an InputStream, while 'CryptoHandler.encryptedStream()' give an OutputStream. I have a test, which I have put into update No. 1.